# haskell writing constructors that do work in them

Tags: haskell, data-structures, constructor

i have a few questions

Im writing this constructor called rope which i have like this

```
  data Rope = TextRope{ropeText :: String}
            | ConcatRope{rope1 :: Rope, rope2 :: Rope}
            | SubRope{subRopetext :: Rope, starting :: Integer, ending :: Integer}
            deriving Show
```

First off when i make a TextRope like this

```
*Main> let s =TextRope "why"
*Main> s
TextRope {ropeText = "why"}
*Main>
```

when i do s i want to just get the string of the constructor which is why and im not really sure about that.

Also curious about concat and sub constructors. Specifically it seems like to me you are calling these two constructors there is things happening, you are returning the result of concatenating rope 1 and rope 2 together, im not sure how to describe that in this language, you are defining the data structure but somehow the return of that is a result that has to be calculated by the structure

Here are some examples of what how these functions work

```
> let tr = TextRope "Hello,"
> let sr = TextRope " world!"
> let hw = ConcatRope tr sr
> let ow = SubRope hw 4 4
> tr
Hello,
> sr
 world!
> hw
Hello, world!
```

Sort of confused overall, new to haskell constructors and datatypes, so some pointers would be helpful (not c pointers though!)

Comment: Haskell constructors are not like Java or C++ constructors.  Rather, they are more like the "tag" in a tagged union.  They don't "do work" but rather they "declare shape".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Data constructors never do work.  They only hold the data you pass into them.  If you want work to be done, you should define what are called *smart constructors*, which are just functions that perform some operation before passing it to the actual constructor.  An example might be

```
data Fraction = Fraction
    { numerator :: Int
    , denominator :: Int
    } deriving (Eq)

(%) :: Int -> Int -> Fraction
x % y =
    let (a, b) = reduce x y
    in Fraction a b

-- Reduces a fraction to it's simplest terms
reduce :: Int -> Int -> (Int, Int)
reduce num den = undefined
```

Here you wouldn't export the `Fraction` constructor from your module, just the `%` function that constructs one in the most reduced form.

The other problem you have is that you want your constructors to print out differently.  You can achieve this by not deriving `Show`.  However, I will warn that the Haskell convention is that `show . read = read . show = id`, which wouldn't hold for what you want to do.  This isn't a strict convention, though, and there's nothing stopping you from doing something like:

```
data Rope = <your implementation minus the deriving Show bit>

instance Show Rope where
    show (TextRope t) = t
    show (ConcatRope r1 r2) = show r1 ++ show r2
    show (SubRope r starting ending) = <exercise left to reader>
```

---

As an aside, I would recommend against having a sum type of records with different field names, this can lead to problems where your program type-checks but contains errors that can be caught at compile time if written differently.  For example, what would happen if you had the code

```
> ropeText (ConcatRope (TextRope "Hello, ") (TextRope "world!"))
```

This would cause an error and crash your program!  Instead, it looks like you just want a `Rope` type with `concat` and `subRope` functions, so you could implement it very simply as

```
data Rope = Rope String deriving (Eq)

concatRope :: Rope -> Rope -> Rope
concatRope (Rope r1) (Rope r2) = Rope (r1 ++ r2)

-- Why use Integer instead of Int?  You might find it's easier to implement this function
subRope :: Rope -> Integer -> Integer -> Rope
subRope (Rope r) start end = Rope $ substr start end r
    where substr s e text = <exercise left to reader>
```

Now there's absolutely no way to have an illegal rope operation, the only difference is now you have to use `concatRope` in place of `ConcatRope` and `subRope` in place of `SubRope`.  You're guaranteed that these functions will do what you want, you don't have some complicated type that doesn't help you anyway.

Comment: thank you so much for the insight, this helped so much.

Comment: @Eigenvalue I will add that it's important to remember that in Haskell, data types are just a structure for holding values, nothing more.  In Haskell, we do our best to separate the definition of the data from the actions we want to perform on them.  In most OOP languages, the structure and the operations are tightly coupled in the same definition.  While there are advantages to both, it's certainly easier to reason about your code when you can mathematically prove that any function that constructs a value of your type produces a valid structure, letting you track down bugs easier.

Answer (score 2):

if you don't implement your own show (not with auto-deriving) you will have a harder time getting what you want.

But if you do it's kindof easy:

```
data Rope = TextRope{ropeText :: String}
            | ConcatRope{rope1 :: Rope, rope2 :: Rope}
            | SubRope{subRopetext :: Rope, starting :: Integer, ending :: Integer}

instance Show Rope where
    show (TextRope s) = s
    show (ConcatRope a b) = show a ++ show b
```

I'm sure you'll find the implementation for the `SubRope` case youself ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your example code and your example interactive results don't match.  This is how you've defined `Rope`:

```
data Rope = TextRope{ropeText :: String}
          | ConcatRope{rope1 :: Rope, rope2 :: Rope}
          | SubRope{subRopetext :: Rope, starting :: Integer, ending :: Integer}
          deriving Show
```

The `deriving Show` part is key there; we'll see how.

Later you show this example output:

```
> let tr = TextRope "Hello,"
> let sr = TextRope " world!"
> let hw = ConcatRope tr sr

> hw
Hello, world!
```

With the code that I just showed, actually, what you'll see is the following:

```
> hw
ConcatRope { rope1 = TextRope "Hello,", rope2 = TextRope " world!" }
```

The only way we could get the output that you describe is if we got rid of the `deriving Show` clause in your definition of `Rope`, and wrote this:

```
instance Show Rope where
    show (TextRope text) = text
    show (ConcatRope r1 r2) = show r1 ++ show r2
    show (SubRope rope start end) = ...
```